# 413 (Payload Too Large) when upload is made on Heroku platform

Tags: amazon-s3, autodesk-forge, autodesk, autodesk-data-management

I've made migration once according to official tutorials with Direct-to-S3 approach.

The problem is that when I upload a model (200 MB) in localhost, there's no problem and the files are uploaded. If I want to upload it on the deployed platform, it's giving me `413 (Payload Too Large)` error. I tested a smaller size file upload just to be sure if it's really about file size and the upload was successful.

For upload URL endpoint:

`buckets/${bucketKey}/objects/${encodeURIComponent(objectKey)}/signeds3upload?parts=${parts}&firstPart=${firstPart}`

I've added `&useCdn=true` but I still receive 413 error. At the same time I've upgraded the Heroku performance by changing dynos but this didn't help as well. I'm using Cloudflare, Heroku and Node.js.

What can be done to increase file size on uploads?

Comment: Make sure that you also changed application configuration, it's probably ENV or config setting you need to adjust.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like this could be a limitation on the Heroku side. When uploading the 200MB file, are you generating just a single upload URL for uploading the entire file? If so, consider splitting the data into multiple smaller chunks, and upload those separately.

Comment: I'm uploading the file by chunks, like it was coded in the blog posts for Direct-to-S3. It could be Cloudflare issue too but like said, if the upload is made by chunks, why it is giving an error of 413 ?

Comment: Where exactly are you getting the 413 error from? Is it from the `developer.api.autodesk.com` server? Or is it when you actually try to upload the chunk to the AWS S3 URL?

Comment: I'm getting now Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET error.. I see it on the browser console from the function where ajax post call is made to oss/objects endpoint.

Comment: So you are now getting a different error? What have you changed? Have you tried uploading a small file, and does that also fail? Have you tried contacting Heroku support?

Comment: I've contacted Heroku support and yes small file can be uploaded successfully. But the limiting is from Cloudflare side. Witthout Cloudflare Registrar everything works as expected. Thanks for your time.